# jquery loop through images and replace src

Tags: jquery, each

I need to loop through all images in DOM and replace a specific source.
Don't know why this isn't working.

UPDATE
I need to search and replace in the src of each image. If the source contains "old/directory" ONLY then replace to "new/directory".

```
jQuery('.element img').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace("old/directory", "new/directory"));
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by specific.

Comment: **Note:** You could use `this.src = this.src.replace("text","text2");`. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/phXjb/

Comment: Is your code being run in a document ready call or at the end of the body?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console or more code we can see? Do your elements have that element class?

Comment: Totally my BAD. Rookie mistake. There was another script changing the .element class. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP had other code that was changing a class causing the posted code to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all the DOM elements are ready before changing your image source by wrapping your code inside `$(function() { })`

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('.element img').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace("old/directory", "new/directory"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(function () {
    $('.element img').each(function () {
        var oldDir = "old/directory";

        if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf(oldDir) > -1) {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(oldDir, "new/directory"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this...

```
$('.element img').each(function () {
    var img = $(this);
    if(img.attr("src").indexOf("old/directory") > -1) {
        img.attr('src', "new/directory");
    }
});
```

Comment: But this would apply the new/directory to all images even if the src doesn't contain the string old/directory...am I right?

Comment: This would loop through the images and set the source for each one to "new/directory".

Comment: Still wrong. You're setting the src for every image to "new/directory" and that's not what's needed here. Plus, as the comment in the question shows, the code works, so something else is the issue.